# Caught TypeError while rendering: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'use_decimal'

Tags: jquery, python, django, typeerror

While running the program i am getting the  following error message

```
Caught TypeError while rendering: __init__() got an unexpected keyword
argument 'use_decimal'
```

Here  is my code 
i am using jquery 1.6.4

```
def load_charts(chart_list=None, render_to=''):
    embed_script = (
      '<script type="text/javascript">\n'
      'var _chartit_hco_array = %s;\n</script>\n'
      '<script src="%s" type="text/javascript">\n</script>')

    if chart_list is not None:
        if isinstance(chart_list, (Chart, PivotChart)):
            chart_list = [chart_list]
        chart_list = [c.hcoptions for c in chart_list]
        render_to_list = [s.strip() for s in render_to.split(',')]
        for hco, render_to in izip_longest(chart_list, render_to_list):
            if render_to:
                hco['chart']['renderTo'] = render_to
        embed_script = (embed_script % (simplejson.dumps(chart_list, 
                                                         use_decimal=True),
                                        CHART_LOADER_URL))
    else:
        embed_script = embed_script %((), CHART_LOADER_URL)
    return mark_safe(embed_script)
```

Comment: thanx Daniel Roseman for editing

Comment: Well, `simplejson.dumps` doesn't take the argument `use_decimal`. Where did you get the impression that it does? (And I've no idea why you think it's relevant that you're using jQuery.)

Comment: @DanielRoseman - we wrote the same at the same time (although I posted it as an answer). It seems however that the parameter is documented at least for version 2.1.0 though! (see my edits)

Comment: Not sure why this has been downvoted... I just got the exact same error message for the exact same reason.  It's a thing!

Answer (score 2):

The signature of `simplejson.dumps` is (see [documentation](http://svn.red-bean.com/bob/simplejson/tags/simplejson-1.3/docs/module-simplejson.html#dumps)):

```
dumps(obj, skipkeys=False, ensure_ascii=True, 
      check_circular=True, allow_nan=True, cls=None)
```

as you can see there is no `use_decimal` parameter... yet you are calling it like this:

```
simplejson.dumps(chart_list, use_decimal=True)
```

---

**EDIT:** Actually a bit more digging brought up [this other documentation](http://simplejson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/simplejson-2.1.0/docs/index.html). It seems that the `use_decimal` parameter was added somewhere along the version of simplejson library... I would suggest to upgrade you library version to the latest available one then!

Comment: Well discovered, but the OP tagged the question with `django` so I guess they are using the version of simplejson included with that framework, which is 2.0.7.

Comment: NOw i am  getting                                                             Caught TypeError while rendering: Decimal('51.8') is not JSON serializable

Comment: @ritvik - Well, I suppose if you try to use Decimal with a version of the library that does not support it you _will_ get problems... Anyhow: this is another problem, so I suggest you open a new question specific on how to serialise decimals with that version of the library: I'm sure you will get more and more qualified answers than I could ever provide you with on this specific topic! :)

Answer (score 1):

To save another soul the agonizing hours spent.

```
    pip install simplejson
```

NB: This should be done in your [project virtual env](http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/02/09/starting-a-django-project-the-right-way/).