# Django/Chartit NameError: global name 'MonthlyWeatherByCity' is not defined

Tags: python, django, highcharts

I am trying to product plots in my Django site using Chartit. I am following the official tutorial, but getting the following error as I try to navigate to my page.

```
NameError at /chart/ <br>
global name 'MonthlyWeatherByCity' is not defined
```

I would appreciate any tips that might solve this issue. I am using the demo database from Chartit, I have run `python manage.py syncdb` before I started the server.

models.py looks like:

```
from django.db import models

class MonthlyWeatherByCity(models.Model):
    month = models.IntegerField()
    boston_temp = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=1)
    houston_temp = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=1)
```

view.py looks like:

```
from chartit import DataPool,Chart
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.template import Context,loader
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponse

def weather_chart_view(request):
    #Step 1: Create a DataPool with the data we want to retrieve.
    weatherdata = \
        DataPool(
           series=
            [{'options': {
               'source': MonthlyWeatherByCity.objects.all()},
              'terms': [
                'month',
                'houston_temp',
                'boston_temp']}
             ])

    #Step 2: Create the Chart object
    cht = Chart(
            datasource = weatherdata,
            series_options =
              [{'options':{
                  'type': 'line',
                  'stacking': False},
                'terms':{
                  'month': [
                    'boston_temp',
                    'houston_temp']
                  }}],
            chart_options =
              {'title': {
                   'text': 'Weather Data of Boston and Houston'},
               'xAxis': {
                    'title': {
                       'text': 'Month number'}}})

    #Step 3: Send the chart object to the template.
    return render_to_response({'weatherchart': cht})
```

chart.html in template looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/highcharts.js"></script>
    {% load chartit %}
    {{ weatherchart|load_charts:"container" }}

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't imported your model. At the top of your `views.py` add:

```
from .models import MonthlyWeatherByCity
```

Comment: I believe you meant ``.models``. It fixed the original issue, but I'm getting the following message now. ``TemplateDoesNotExist at /chart/`` then ``{'weatherchart': <chartit.charts.Chart object at 0x7f02cc02fc50>}``.

Comment: You need to pass your template name in the last line of your view code. Thus, change to: `return render_to_response('chart.html', {'weatherchart': cht})`. Also, nice catch on .models. I'll edit it.

Comment: That's how it is now... ``return render_to_response('chart.html',{'weatherchart': cht})`` ... but I get this TypeError -- ``__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'use_decimal'``

Comment: Looks like some other people (i.e. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644060/caught-typeerror-while-rendering-init-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument)) have had similar problems. We're getting pretty far from the original problem so I'd start a new question.

Comment: Yeah, I think so too. I have seen others face it too. I'll probably create another question.

Comment: Found the solution. Need to install the 'simplejson' package. That's what solved the ``use_decimal`` issue.